# Symfony2: Extend php-sdk kit to custom bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, bundle

Using Symfony2, Twig, and Prismic:

I have looked at the following resources, but I am still unclear how to extend certain methods in Symfony2

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

There is a prismic folder in my vendors directory, which includes the following dirs:

```
vendors/prismic
     php-sdk
     prismic-bundle
```

For my application, I duplicated the prismic-bundle directory and moved it here:

```
src/VAP/Bundle/PrismicBundle
```

then changed the AppKernal.php to include this bundle:

```
// new Prismic\Bundle\PrismicBundle\PrismicBundle() ..removed the connection to the vendor dir

new VAP\Bundle\PrismicBundle\PrismicBundle() ..use this custom directory
```

which works fine.

However, there are methods in the php-sdk directory that are called from my custom PrismicBundle, which I need to extend or override. For instance, a twig template may call

`var.getStructuredText('blog.body').asHtml(ctx.linkResolver)`

which is located here:

vendor/prismic/php-sdk/src/Prismic/Fragment/StructuredText.php

How/where would I create a file that would extend/overwrite the above file?

I am also confused if php-sdk is a bundle, or is it part of the original PrismicBundle from the vendor directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you say that you duplicated the PrismicBundle in your src folder, why did you not use the bundle inheritence process ?

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'PrismicBundle';
}
```

For you question, you have to change the behavior of the prismic php-sdk, possible reasons:

- 1) This sdk is not well built
- 2) You do not use it correctly
- 3) You want a very custom behavior not supported by prismic

IMO, possible solutions are:

- 1) Fork the sdk to add compatibility to your need
- 2) Think about a different way to reach your need
- 3) Create a new service in your custom PrismicBundle that call prismic api as you want.

Faor your final question, afaik prismic/php-sdk is the api implementation in raw php, and prismic/prismic-bundle is a bridge between this raw php SDK and Symfony, implementing services and all comodities provided by Symfony.

Comment: I tried using inheritance, but could not get it to work properly. When using inheritance, where would I put my custom function that would override the one from the vendor?

Comment: This doc explains how overwrite any part of a bundle: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

If you want to overwrite a service from the PrismicBundle, check out the "CompilerPass" section.

Comment: It's important to use bundle inheritance because you can more easily upgrade to newer versions of the bundle but only overriding the features you need to customize.  I have had some issues when overriding twig templates and only needed to clear the cache for the new file to take effect, even in development stage.

Comment: IN the vendor directory, I am unsure if php-sdk is even a bundle. The dir structure is as follows: vendor/prismic/src/Prismic/Fragment/StructuredText.php. The docs are not very clear on how to override the StructuredText class with a custom one. The docs reference overriding a controller in a Bundle. I am trying to extend a Class in the php-sdk directory. Is that a service?

Comment: is this the bundle you are using [prismicio](https://github.com/prismicio/SymfonyBundle)?

Comment: Yes, but the one with the class I want to extend is prismic/php-sdk, which is here: https://packagist.org/packages/prismic/php-sdk. My composer json is setup like so: "prismic/prismic-bundle": "dev-master", "prismic/php-sdk": "1.0.4.*@dev"

Comment: IN prismic/php-sdk, it's the StructuredText class in /Fragment

Comment: prismic/php-sdk is not a Symfony Bundle, you cannot overwrite it. As I said, you should either fork prismic/php-sdk if you think the modification you want could be usefull for other people.

Comment: Ok, so how would I include a copy of my own sdk repo? Should I copy the sdk directory to my src directory, then add it to AppKernel? I tried that, and it cannot find the class needed to register. Or should I just remove the sdk require from composer and make updates in the vendor directory files?